# Não Consigo pegar um Array

Tags: php, array, array-multidimensional

Eu estou tentando pegar um valor dentro de um array, porem não imprime nada do campo id, que é o campo que eu quero pegar

```
$jsonc = file_get_contents("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/tv?query=todo%20o%20mundo%20odeia%20o%20chris&api_key=b5ad6a9f75ea4e476b5f08b524ddf83d");
$epjson = json_decode($jsonc);    
print_r($epjson -> id);
```

OBS: Quando faço apenas o `print_r($epjson);` imprime isso:

> stdClass Object ( [page] => 1 [total_results] => 1 [total_pages] => 1
>   [results] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [original_name] =>
>   Everybody Hates Chris [id] => 252 [name] => Everybody Hates Chris
>   [vote_count] => 68 [vote_average] => 6.82 [poster_path] =>
>   /dM0IUKmrjyhFskt0ZBMbbfWxRIQ.jpg [first_air_date] => 2005-09-22
>   [popularity] => 10.150596 [genre_ids] => Array ( [0] => 35 )
>   [original_language] => en [backdrop_path] =>
>   /xYLcbJoQEowXFVqe94A37CIC0Tq.jpg [overview] => Everybody Hates Chris
>   is an American television narrative sitcom that depicts the troubled
>   teenage experiences of comedian Chris Rock while growing up in
>   Bedford-Stuyvesant, Brooklyn, New York City. The show is set between
>   1982 and 1987, but Rock himself was a teenager between 1978 and 1983.
>   Rock grew up with a boy named Kenny Montero, whom he has often
>   referred to as the inspiration for a lot of the episodes. In many of
>   his interviews, Rock has described Kenny as the reason he got into
>   comedy in the first place. The show's title parodies the hit CBS
>   sitcom Everybody Loves Raymond, in which Rock stated: "Everybody Loves
>   Raymond, but Everybody Hates Chris!". The show's lead actors are Tyler
>   James Williams, Terry Crews, Tichina Arnold, Tequan Richmond, Imani
>   Hakim, and Vincent Martella. In 2008, the The CW moved Everybody Hates
>   Chris and The Game to the Friday night death slot. The fourth season
>   of the series premiered Friday, October 3, 2008, at 8:00PM
>   Eastern/7:00PM Central. On May 21, 2009, The CW announced that it had
>   cancelled Everybody Hates Chris. Prior to this, Rock announced that
>   the end of season 4 matched up with his own past—dropping out of high
>   school to become a comedian—and that it was time to end the show.
>   [origin_country] => Array ( [0] => US ) ) ) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe a estrutura da informação na API que está a utilizar:

```
{
    "page": 1,
    "total_results": 1,
    "total_pages": 1,
    "results": [{
                "original_name": "Everybody Hates Chris",
                "id": 252,
                "name": "Everybody Hates Chris",
                "vote_count": 68,
                ....
```

O `id` não está logo na raiz mas sim dentro do array `results`, por isso deve aceder ao mesmo com:

```
print_r($epjson->results[0]->id);
```

Se tiver mais que um resultado e quiser o `id` dos vários resultados deve utilizar um `for` para os percorrer.

Comment: Obrigado. Funcionou 100%.